# What's the best way build intranet in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, intranet

Using Drupal 7.26, Zen Theme

I would like to build an intranet with 3 layers:

- login (thin header, nothing else)
- Dashboard (divs for major business divisions i.e. sales along with sidebar)
- Content (content with sidebar)

i can get the first two using page-front.tpl and page.tpl, but the third layer also has page.tpl formatting. can i create a custom page format i.e. page-show-tpl or is their a better way to address this (preferably not panels).

Thx !

ken

Answer (score 0):

It's best answered by using Google search.

But just in case of whatever - the two major players are Open Atrium and Drupal Commons. Look these projects up on drupal.org.